# Capturar imagen de una web

Tags: php, web, imagen, url

me gustaría crear una imagen en mi servidor, la imagen debe contener la web por ejemplo si le pongo $url = "google.es"; debe dde mostrar una imagen con la web de google

lo he intentado hacer con herramientas de terceros pero no lo he conseguido, alguien me podría ayudar  para capturar la imagen y almacenarla en el servidor??
Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Hola Pablo. ¿Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora y qué errores concretos tienes?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mas info. Sin esa explicacion, la pregunta puede no estar clara o ser demasiado amplia.. Un saludo

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo usando canvas y javascript: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: así es como lo intentaba antes

Comment: sin codigo no te podemos ayudar :(

Comment: No ser por que no se me ha guardado el comentario anterior...
echo "<img src=http://free.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=x&url='$enlace3'>";

Comment: a ver, ya conseguí mostrar la imagen a través de una API de google, pero me falta copiarla en el servidor, alguien me pude echar una mano??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a ver, ya conseguí mostrar la imagen a través de una API de google, pero me falta copiarla en el servidor, alguien me pude echar una mano??os pongo el codigo

function getGooglePageSpeedScreenshot($site, $img_tag_attributes = "border='1'") {
    #initialize
    $use_cache = false;
    $apc_is_loaded = extension_loaded('apc');

```
#set $use_cache
if($apc_is_loaded) {
    apc_fetch("thumbnail:".$site, $use_cache);
}

if(!$use_cache) {
    $image = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v1/runPagespeed?url=http://$site&screenshot=true");
    $image = json_decode($image, true);
    $image = $image['screenshot']['data'];
    if($apc_is_loaded) {
        apc_add("thumbnail:".$site, $image, 2400);
    }
}

$image = str_replace(array('_', '-'), array('/', '+'), $image);
return "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$image."\"
```

}

```
echo getGooglePageSpeedScreenshot($dominio, 'class="thumbnail"');
```